# What is the meaning of 会 in 我在工作中常常会运用“峰终定律”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

作为电视节目主持人，我在工作中常常会运用“峰终定律”。例如，做节目时，与开幕式相比，我们宁可把更多的精力集中在闭幕式上，这样可以加强观众对节目的印象。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 17. What is the meaning of 会?

Baidu translate: As a TV presenter, I often apply the "peak to end law" in my work.

Google translate: As a TV presenter, I often use the "peak-end rule" in my work.

As you can see, both engines do not translate it. Does it have here the classical meaning "can", "to be able to"?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the context, '会' can mean

1. "will; would". e.g. 明天[**会**]下雨 - it [**will**] rain tomorrow (rain is something that will/ would happen)
2. "can; know how to". e.g. 我[**会**]畫油畫 - I [**can**] paint oil painting (painting is a skill that one can perform)

Simply saying 会运用 or 会运用峰终定律 doesn't clearly indicate which meaning of 会 is referred to

However, with the word 常常 (often) we know 会 here means 'would' and not 'can'

常常会运用峰终定律 = would often use 峰终定律

If you can do something, you can always do it. It wouldn't be "*often can*"

Answer (score 1):

As a native Chinese speaker, the following expressions are all acceptable to me and mean the same.

1. 我在工作中常常会运用...
2. 我常常会在工作中运用...
3. 我在工作中常常运用...
4. 我常常在工作中运用...

Here, "会" has no actual meaning, or slightly emphasize the statement if you have to figure out the difference. Comperativly, let's say "as a matter of fact" and "in fact",longer expression seems to be more serious.

Answer (score 0):

会 has different meaning in different context.

Common usages:

1. 会合(together), 会话(conversation): same as the word-building root `con-`, means together;
2. 会游泳(can swim), 会英语(can speak English): means 'can';
3. 机会(chance)
4. 一会儿(for a while, in a minute)
5. 会心，体会: means 'understand'

Example sentences:

1. 我会游泳。 - I can swim.
2. 请给我一个感谢你的机会。 - Please give me a chance to thank you.
3. 他们聊了一会儿。 - They chatted for a while.

ps: I'm a chinese who is learning English. I hope these tips will help you.

Answer (score 0):

我常常会翻译常常会！

常常会： most of the time, not always

作为电视节目主持人，
As a TV anchorman,
我在工作中常常会运用“峰终定律”。
I **will often**  use the "finish with a flourish rule" in my work,
例如，
for example,
做节目时，
during a programme,
与开幕式相比，
compared to our opening,
我们宁可把更多的精力集中在闭幕式上，
we prefer to concentrate more (energy) on the finish,
这样可以加强观众对节目的印象。
that way, we can strengthen the spectators impression of our programme.

Not sure that strategy will work, if most of the programme is dull and boring!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question on the word 会.

In the sentence 我在工作中常常会运用“峰终定律”. 常常会 means "as a common practice".

Please study the following examples for words 会，能，想.

"我们晚上去看电影，你会去吗？" "我不会去。" (Would you like to go with us?) (more politely).

"我们晚上去看电影，你能去吗？" "我不能去。" (Can you go with us?) (Do you have time? Do you have anything else to do?)

"我们晚上去看电影，你想去吗？" "我不想去。" (Do you want to go with us?) （you decide for yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simple. here 会 is optional, redundant, not necessary.

There two are the same:

- 我在工作中常常会运用-峰终定律
- 我在工作中常常运用-峰终定律